# Task Scheduler .bat file run prompt

Tags: batch-file, windows-10, scheduled-tasks

Currently I continue my work on my ICT (Information Collector Tool) which is just taking note of the Hardware Specs, Serial Number, Programs, etc. of a PC to monitor it's health in case RAM breaks or in case the users start installing Software we aren't aware of. Of course they normally don't have Admin rights to install anything but non the less I would prefer to have a list ready in case we see something suspicious going on.

So I finally got to a stage where I try to work out a way to run the file so the user doesn't have to do anything nor got to see that it is running. This is just to avoid "stupid" questions. Ideally I would run a hidden instance of this but the Task Scheduler doesn't seem to accept the hidden attribute of Windows 10s Task Scheduler.

This is the line the task is running: `cmd.exe /c start /min /D "\\<IP>\<PATH>\ICT" ICT.bat`

Anyway. The work around is to start the window minimized which is absolutely fine by me. My current issue is the following, the Task Scheduler successfully start the bat file, however it still prompts me to click on a Run button as shown on Picture 1
[image: Picture 1]

Does anyone know of a way to solve this issue? Do I have to add the PC or script somewhere in the Internet option > Security tab? If possible I would like to only use the Task scheduler & the bat file that should run. I saw about some Powershell or vbs scripts but I don't really want to turn this into an inception of scripts where Script A start Script B to Start Script C. And who can guarantee me that the middle man script also gets a prompt. ;)

Every help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Can't you configure the scheduled task to be run as administrator?

Comment: Right click on the bat file and unblock it.

Comment: @Dominique I already run it as admin and I specified to "Run with highest privileges" to make it work. I know for a fact that Windows 10 requires you to run my .bat file as an admin even tho it wasn't necessary to run under Win 7. It may be related to the fact that it safes the files for the writting under C:\ or because it is a security from microsoft to prevent normal users from running bat files if no admin.
      Squashman what do you mean "unblock it" the permissions are read and execute and I will definetly not allow anyone to make modifications as this may result in a big problem.

Comment: @Squashman Just checked and I don't have such an option under Properties > General. I also double checked and it's not because I try to access it from my own PC. We all work with Win 10 Pro 20H2 if that helps

Answer (score 1):

1. Press Windows Key + S and enter Internet options. Select Internet
   Options from the list of results.
2. When the Internet Properties window opens, go to the Security tab
   and click on the Custom Level button.
3. A list of settings will appear. Locate "Launching applications and
   unsafe files" and select Enable. Now click OK to save changes.

Got it from [here](https://windowsreport.com/open-file-security-warning/).

Disabling UAC prompt maybe helps too. Unfortunately, you will have to make all of these changes on each computer or make an .reg key. Good luck! Works on pretty much all Windows versions.

***Hope this helps,

K.***

Comment: Even tho this would be the easiest solution, which I also thought about, I would rather not disable the UAC prompt as this makes our users report their issues most of the times, which is good for us. Also when I had a look on the internet options I realised that it was managed by the GPO so that's also a no. ^^'
Now I also realize why that never was an issue on the PCs of my former jobs. There we disabled it by default. ^^'

Comment: So you fix the problem?

Comment: @VarmintLP if you fixed the problem, please consider marking the answer as the accepted.

Comment: The thing is, I would be glad to mark your answer as the solution but my  first reply says that it would be the easiest solution, however I cannot disable the UAC or make changes to "Internet Options" > "Security" due to security reasons. So currently the problem isn't solve.

Comment: You asked a question about how to disable user consent to open or run system security files on your network, and why you could not tamper with Internet Options for security reasons? Does not make sense.
Perhaps this is not the way you have to go.

Comment: I did not ask on how to disable user consent. I more asked to find a way to either accept the prompt and click on yes or to exclude this specific script from this.

Comment: I believe that this is the only way to do this.

Comment: I don't know. And that is what I try to find out with asking here.